# Rails : How does "new" action called "create" action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am following this tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/getting_started.html to build my rails app in version 3.2.13 . If you go to the section 6.9 you will find controller and view for creating new posts . Here I do not get how `@post` variable is passed from `new` action to `create` action and where is `create` function called ? Also , I faced the same problem while working on `edit` and update `actions` . Please guide me through this .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not passed to `create` action, it's instantiated again with params you pass from the form displayed with `new` action.

`create` action is called with POST request to the path specified in config/routes.rb, leading to specific controller and action.

Comment: Thanx Marek . One more query , where is the "create" function called?

Comment: @nerdiplayboy run `rake routes` to see your routes, `GET` is mapped to `index` and `POST` is mapped to `create`.

Answer (score 2):

`@post` is not passed from `new` to `create` the `params` hash is passed into the create method `@post` is then set using the `new` method of the model not the controller. `create` calls `new` and then `save` and returns the object. `new` returns the object without saving and then `save` returns the validity of the object. That is why the create method in the controller calls `new` and then has a conditional statement for `save`. It is basically saying initialize this object then if it is a valid object do one thing if it is not do another. The create action is not called because of this check.

```
#this will return true if valid or false if invalid
  Post.new(params[:post]).save 
#this will always return the Post object which conditionally is true in Ruby
  Post.create(params[:post])
#To use the create in a conditional statement it would be 
  Post.create(params[:post]).valid? || Post.create(param[:post]).save
```

The last line is unnecessarily redundant and thus why the example uses `new` followed by `save`.

`create` method for a Model is more succinct but probably best to use when you know the object is valid.

Hope this gives you a better understanding but if you are still confused please let me know and I will try to explain further.