# Why is it that the Rails convention is to write @example = Example.new twice, once in the new and then in the create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to understand the reasoning behind writing the line of code 
`@example = Example.new` two times.

According to the answer below, it seems that the model object is instantiated twice but I don't understand why we need to instantiate the object for the new method.

[Rails : How does "new" action called "create" action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006821/rails-how-does-new-action-called-create-action)

```
def new
    @example = Example.new
  end

  def create
    @example = Example.new(example_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @example
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the blank object because your view won't be able to build a form for `example` in that case. Usually people are building forms when they do that and to use rails form builders, the correct model object is required (in this case `@example`), otherwise [**form builder**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) will never know about the attributes of that model object it has to build.

```
<%= form_for @example do |f| %>
  Name: <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

In above, without @example, the `form_for` won't be able to figure out that it has to go to POST `create` action of `Example`. Nor will it be able to identify `name` field.

In case you want to remove `@example = Example.new` from `new` action, you will have to build the form on your own. But, follow the conventions, it's not recommended.

```
<%= form_tag('/examples') do %>
  Name: <= text_field_tag :name %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In new method when we use `@example = Example.new` we initialise blank object of current model and `@example` is used  to bind the form in views.

```
<%= form_for @example do |f|%>
```

if you see the html for above line it will be like

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/examples" method="post">
```

`@example` in new basically bind the model attributes with form

when we user `@example = Example.new(example_params)` with again initialise the object with the form values i.e. values which user enter in the form and submit.

You can visit the following link to understand more http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I dont get why you cant use the blank object in the new method for the create method. As it seems redundant to initialize an object twice.

Comment: @Blaze not twice because there are different action.

Answer (score 0):

`@example` is not instantiated twice here. These are two different actions. Every time one of them is called, a new instance of the controller class is created. So `@example` only belongs to that instance.

You instantiate `@example` for `#new` so that it can be available in the view. Rails automatically share the instance variables from the controller actions with their corresponding views by copying them over. You do the instantiation in controllers because it is part of the controller's job. This way you have a nice separation of concerns: views don't need to bother with creating variables, only with presenting them.

You can of course do it this way:

```
##controller
def new
end

##new.html.erb
<%example = Example.new%>
<%=form_for example do |f| %>
##code omitted for brevity
```

And it will work. But this is not a good practice as you're mixing different logics in views.